# Large variation in the resulting pagespeed values

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Recently, after the lighthouse update, significant differences in values ​​appeared in the site measurement, with successive measurements of the same project, the differences reached 30 points, for example, before the update, these differences had a maximum of 3 points.

We are positioning ourselves as a company that gives high pointspeed in pagespeed as an advantage, but for any differences, as a result, we cannot rely on numbers. We want to understand:

- Why does such a difference in the resulting values ​​appear?
- How can this difference be reduced?
- Could this be due to the incorrect operation of your algorithms?

The measurements were carried out on our project in production, which had constant values > 90 points before the update.

Check [this](https://domotehnika.by/).

Comment: Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) is likely to be the cause of this if you are dynamically including JS templates etc. as those can be impacted by load order and change the way the page renders. PSI has been updated to version 6.0 so perhaps have a read of the new rules etc. I answered about the new scoring here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063118/2702894 and CLS information can be found here https://web.dev/cls/

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is a CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift) issue. Your CLS numbers are fine.

The variance in Page Speed Insights could be due to your CDN - Content Distribution Network. First-time tests usually are poor as your site gets loaded on CDN cache. Subsequent tests will be faster. Always take the median score from 4-5 runs.

You can also try and disable CDN temporarily. Platforms such as Cloudflare offer developer testing mode to disable CDN temporarily. Try that. You will get more consistent results.